# For any numerable neighbourhood basis of any point there exist a numerable neighbourhood basis totally ordered for the inclusion

Tags: general-topology

Let be $x$ a point of a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and we suppose that there exist a numerable neighbourhood basis $\mathcal{B}(x)\equiv\{B_0,...,B_{n\le\omega}\}$ of $x$: so there exist a numerable neighbourhood basis $\mathcal{B'}(x)=\{B'_0,...,B'_{n\le\omega}\}$ such that $B_{n+1}\subseteq B_n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

To prove the assertion we consider that for any numerable collection of neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}(x)$ of $x$ it result that $\bigcap\mathcal{U}(x)$ is a neighbourood of $X$ and so for any numerable basis $\mathcal{B}(x)\equiv\{B_0,...,B_{n\le\omega}\}$ of $x$ we define the non empty neighbourood collection 
$$
\mathcal{U}(x)=\{\bigcap^n_{i=n}B_i,...,\bigcap^n_{i=1}B_i,\bigcap^n_{i=0}B_i\}
$$ well 
evidently $\mathcal{U}(x)$ is numerable and $\bigcap^n_{i=0}B_i\subseteq\bigcap^n_{i=1}B_i\subseteq...\subseteq\bigcap^n_{i=n}B_i$; furthermore for any neighbourood of $V_x$ of $x$ there exist $B_j\in\mathcal{B}(x)$ such that $\bigcap^n_{i=j}B_i\subseteq B_j\subseteq V_x$ so $\mathcal{U}(x)$ is a numerable neighbourood basis.

Well it seems that the proof is correct for any $n<\omega$, but what happens if $n=\omega$? would still $\bigcap^\omega_{i=n\in\mathbb{N}}B_i$ a neighbourood of $x$?

If the proof is uncorrect, how demonstrate the assertion?

Pheraps instead could I choose the collection

$$\mathcal{U}(x)=\{{B_0\cap(\bigcap^{0}_{i=0}B_i),B_0\cap(\bigcap^{1}_{i=0}}B_i),...,B_0\cap(\bigcap^{n}_{i=0}B_i),...\}?
$$

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: B$_{\omega}$ is a red herring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say it's $(B_n)_{n < \omega}$ as a local base at $x$ (we don't use $\omega$ itself, just its members, which are all $n < \omega$).

Define for all $n \in \omega$: $$U_n = \bigcap_{i \le n} B_n$$

and note that these are open sets containing $x$, just like the $B_n$ are (we have *finite* intersections of open sets every time). Also, trivially, $$\forall n< \omega: U_n \subseteq B_n\tag{1}$$

As $n \le m$ implies $U_m \subseteq U_n$ (we take the intersection of more sets, so we can only get smaller), the $U_n$ are linearly ordered by the reverse order on their indices.

And they still form a local base at $x$: if $x \in O$ and $O$ is open, for some $n_0$ we have $B_{n_0} \subseteq O$ and then $(1)$ tells us that $U_{n_0} \subseteq O$ and we're done.